# reading and printing a text file in Perl

Tags: perl

I have simple question:

### why the first code does not print the first line of the file but the second one does?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $protfile = "file.txt";
open (FH, $protfile);
while (<FH>) {
         print (<FH>);

}
```

---

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $protfile = "file.txt";
open (FH, $protfile);
while (my $file = <FH>) {
         print ("$file");

}
```

Comment: just a side note, use `open (my $FH, "<", $protfile);` instead of `open (FH, $protfile);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are comsuming the first line with the <> operator and then using it again in the print, so the first line has already gone but you are not printing it. <> is the readline operator. You need to print the $_ variable, or assign it to a defined variable as you are doing in the second code. You could rewrite the first:

print;

And it would work, because print uses $_ if you don't give it anything.

Answer (score 5):

Context.

Your first program tests for end-of-file on `FH` by reading the first line, then reads `FH` in list context as an argument to `print`.  That translates to the whole file, as a list with one line per item.  It then tests for EOF again, most likely detects it, and stops.

Your second program iterates by line, each one read in scalar context to variable `$file`, and prints them individually.  It detects EOF by a special case in the `while` syntax.  (see the code samples in [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators))

So the specific reason why your program doesn't print the first line in one case is that it's lost in the argument to `while`.  Do note that the two programs' structure is pretty different: the first only runs a single `while` iteration, while the second iterates once per line.

PS: nowadays, the recommended way to manage files tends towards lexical filehandles (`open my $file, 'name'; print <$file>;`).

Answer (score 2):

When used in *scalar context*, `<FH>` returns the next single line from the file.

When used in *list context*, `<FH>` returns a list of all remaining lines in the file.

`while (my $file = <FH>)` is a scalar context, since you're assigning to a scalar.  `while (<FH>)` is short for `while(defined($_ = <FH>))`, so it is also a scalar context.  `print (<FH>);` makes it a list context, since you're using it as argument to a function that can take multiple arguments.

```
while (<FH>) {
    print (<FH>);
}
```

The `while` part reads the first line into `$_` (which is never used again).  Then the `print` part reads the rest of the lines all at once, then prints them all out again.  Then the `while` condition is checked again, but since there are now no lines left, `<FH>` returns `undef` and the loop quits after just one iteration.

```
while (my $file = <FH>) {
    print ("$file");
}
```

does more what you probably expect: reads and then prints one line during each iteration of the loop.

By the way, `print $file;` does the same as `print ("$file");`

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect.  Perl ensures a single assignment from IO as a loop condition properly terminates on EOF only. (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).  (or simply test it)

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<FH>) {
    print (<FH>);
}
```

use this instead:

```
while (<FH>) {
    print $_;
}
```